# Not able to import MySQL into python on OS X

Tags: python, mysql

```
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/flask_mysqldb/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import MySQLdb
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libmysqlclient.21.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so
  Reason: image not found
```

this is the error I receive when trying to run my flask app on a local server.

Comment: I think, you do not have MySQLdb installed or it has not been installed properly

Comment: @OdamePrince You were right it was not installed correctly, I had to add a config file for MySQL for it to install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to install the python connector for mysql.

```
 > brew install mysql-connector-c
 > pip install mysql-python`
```

After installation, your import should work fine.

NB: I assume that you have already installed [homebrew](http://brew.sh/)

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to do, but hard to remember the correct spelling:

pip install mysqlclient
If you need 1.2.x versions (legacy Python only), use pip install MySQL-python

Note: Some dependencies might have to be in place when running the above command. Some hints on how to install these on various platforms:

Ubuntu 14, Ubuntu 16, Debian 8.6 (jessie)
sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev libmysqlclient-dev
Fedora 24:
sudo dnf install python python-devel mysql-devel redhat-rpm-config gcc
Mac OS
brew install mysql-connector-c
if that fails, try this

brew install mysql